# What is the benefit of register service in app.module.ts vs individual component in angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript

For example if I register a service in `app.module.ts` I have to do the following to make a service available in a component

`app.module.ts`

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent/mycomponent.component';
import { MyService } from './services/myservice.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [MyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

`mycomponent.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../services/myservice.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _myService: MyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._myService.test()
    }

}
```

But I could also just register in the component itself to use it without having to add anything to `app.module.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../services/myservice.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _myService: MyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._myService.test()
    }

}
```

I am curious, what is the difference for each way?

Comment: Providers defined on a module level become part of global injector, read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add your service in the root providers of your application, all components will inject the same instance of the service. So only one instance will be created during the application. In this case you can keep `state` in your service.

When you add your service in the providers of your `Component`, every time a new instance of **that** component will be created, new `instance` of service also will be created. In this case you can't keep `state` in this type of service,

Depending on your logic provide where you need, but it's common case to provide all services in the root module.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com What do you mean? Which provider?

Comment: what happen when you add the provider to both the root and the individual component?

Comment: Provider search will start from the `Component` and goes from parent to parent and finaly to root. When first is found, it will be injected. In depending on the hierarchy of your components, new instance or single instance will be injected.